# How Do I Access Document Fields From Meteor Spacebars #with Template Helper?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, spacebars

This code should display document fields first_name and last_name, instead it generates an "Uncaught Error: Unknown helper 'first_name'" error:

```
# In Template.
{{#with doc}}
<p>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</p>
{{/with}}

# Template 'doc' property.
_.extend Template.doc,
  doc: -> Docs.findOne {_id: Session.get 'doc_id'}
```

If I replace #with and findOne() with #each and find() it works fine:

```
# In Template.
{{#each doc}}
<p>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</p>
{{/each}}

# Template 'doc' property.
_.extend Template.doc,
  doc: -> Docs.find {_id: Session.get 'doc_id'}
```

This post suggests that #with should work [Turn a meteor method returning a single object into a context for handlebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160455/turn-a-meteor-method-returning-a-single-object-into-a-context-for-handlebar)

I'm using Meteor 0.3.7

Answer (score 0):

`doc` needs to be a key in the result (pardon my js, I've converted it to coffee I don't know how to directly in coffee that well). It would be better to just use a direct reference though.

Try this (with findOne):

```
_.extend Template.doc,
doc: ->
doc: Docs.findOne(_id: Session.get("doc_id"))
```